# Use object_recognition_kitchen with a ROS 3D Sensor not supported by OpenNI?

Tags: ros, openni, realsense, object-recognition-kitchen

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use object recognition kitchen with the Intel RealSense sr300 sensor, which is working with standard 3d sensor messages in ROS.
I was wondering, Is it possible to use ORK with any ROS supported 3d sensor? If not how much work would it be to modify ORK to support standard ROS messages instead of the OpenNI interface?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/230360/use-object_recognition_kitchen-with-a-ros-3d-sensor-not-supported-by-openni?/) by [Link](https://answers.ros.org/users/483/link/) on ROS Answers with karma: 228 on 2016-03-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/object-recognition-kitchen/openni/object-recognition-kitchen/KiXsCxP_uMY/VpN6yhx1M2QJ) provides a solution to the problem of using generic ROS sensor messages in place of the OpenNI interface.
I have not tested it yet but will confirm if/when this works.

---

Originally posted by [Link](https://answers.ros.org/users/483/link/) with karma: 228 on 2016-03-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0